# Skim,emacs,sublime text3, backward search doesn't work

Tags: forward-inverse-search

My working enviroment follows:

- OS: OS X Mavericks 10.9.2
- Skim: 1.4.8
- Editors: emacs-mac with AucTeX (Homebrew), sublime 3 with LaTeXtools (all versions are up-to-date)

I have met a strange issue that the backward search shortcut of Skim is invalid while the forward search works well for me (at least when used with emacs, the line chosen was highlighting, although the specific word was not marked). In sublime, which was weird, the default shortcut `cmd+l,j`  worked now and then and the skim couldn't come to foreground automatically). I failed to use `cmd+shift+left click` to jump from PDF to .tex file with both editors. I've no idea if there are any application conflicts with the keybinding after assigning a new shortcut in system preference for "backward search" in skim.app still couldn't made any change.

**My solution (at least partial):**
Thanks to Christiaan's help and one thread from skim-app-user mailing list, I use the command of `/usr/local/bin/emacsclient` in the custom preset, and it works well. So I think maybe I should make some change to the preset command of Sublime Text 3.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.